# How to analyse the effect of changing parameters in a neural network?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I have built a simple classification neural network with feed-forward and backpropagation and one hidden layer (code below) and I would like to explore the effect of changing:
 - the learning rate
 - the number of nodes in the hidden layer, and
 - the order in which the training examples are presented.

I have found some general comments [here](http://itee.uq.edu.au/~cogs2010/cmc/chapters/BackProp/index2.html) that the larger the learning rate, the quicker the network learns but then there is a danger to have an unstable solution so the learning step is too large to land on the global minimum. Also generally according to this [source](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part3/) from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39873/can-an-artificial-neural-network-with-only-one-hidden-layer-fit-all-purposes-app) if one has more nodes in the hidden layer than a problem of local minima is less of a problem.

However I wasn't able to find resources that would explain how to arrive at a optimal value of these three parameters without just aimlessly trying different values and hoping to land on the right one. Would anyone be able to suggest an approach?

```
clear
% Set up parameters
nInput = 4; % number of nodes in input
nOutput = 1; % number of nodes in output
nHiddenLayer = 7; % number of nodes in th hidden layer
nTrain = 1000; % size of training set
epsilon = 0.01; % learning rate


% Set up the inputs: random coefficients between -1 and 1
trainExamples = 2*rand(nInput,nTrain)-1;
trainExamples(nInput,:) = ones(1,nTrain);  %set the last input to be 1

% Set up the student neurons for both hidden and the output layers
S1(nHiddenLayer,nTrain) = 0;
S2(nOutput,nTrain) = 0;

% The student neuron starts with random weights from both input and the hidden layers
w1 = rand(nInput,nHiddenLayer);
w2 = rand(nHiddenLayer+1,nOutput);

% Calculate the teacher outputs according to the quadratic formula
T = sign(trainExamples(2,:).^2-4*trainExamples(1,:).*trainExamples(3,:));


% Initialise values for looping
nEpochs = 0;
nWrong = nTrain*0.01;
Wrong = [];
Epoch = [];

while(nWrong >= (nTrain*0.01)) % as long as more than 1% of outputs are wrong
    for i=1:nTrain
        x = trainExamples(:,i);
        S1(1:nHiddenLayer,i) = w1'*x;
        S2(:,i) = w2'*[tanh(S1(:,i));1];
        delta1 = tanh(S2(:,i)) - T(:,i); % back propagate
        delta2 = (1-tanh(S1(:,i)).^2).*(w2(1:nHiddenLayer,:)*delta1); % back propagate       
        w1 = w1 - epsilon*x*delta2'; % update
        w2 = w2 - epsilon*[tanh(S1(:,i));1]*delta1'; % update
    end

    outputNN = sign(tanh(S2));
    delta = outputNN - T; % difference between student and teacher
    nWrong = sum(abs(delta/2));
    nEpochs = nEpochs + 1;
    Wrong = [Wrong nWrong];
    Epoch = [Epoch nEpochs];
end
plot(Epoch,Wrong);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "aimlessly trying different values" is of course not a very good strategy. The primary thing to optimize (from my experience), would be the number of hidden layers, the number of hidden neurons in the hidden layers, and the learning rate. I would try to vary one parameter at the time, and then plot the test-error and the training error, to see which learning rate makes the network converge in the best way.

**Edit:** As mentioned by bayerj, there are multiple misleading statements in this answer. The first thing is plotting the test-error. You should of course use a training/validation/test-split (often 80%, 10%, 10%) on your data, and then plot your validation error - not the test error. I left this out in my original answer since it was supposed to be a comment.

The other thing, is that I said that "aimlessly trying different values" was a bad strategy. What I meant here, was not that a randomized strategy for optimizing performance was a bad idea, but that is not how I read "aimlessly trying different values". If you implement a simple randomized search for good parameter-values, the article provided in the answer by bayerj shows, that this performs very well.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer, I guess this is fair enough. I know that if I increase the number of nodes in my hidden layer I get better convergence as there is less chance of having local minima to get stuck in... I think I wanted some kind of a quantitative answer: like when do I stop increasing the number of nodes? I guess I can just rely on common sense and if added computational time for more nodes gains little improvement, than it is OK to stop. Would you mind to migrate it to stats forum if you think it is best? I'll mark your answer if I get no helpful replies...

Comment: actually don't worry, I have just registered on that stat forums and found tons of discussions on this topic. Thanks so much!

Comment: Wrong: aimlessly trying around is one of the best strategies, see my answer. Also you should of course *not* plot the test error but the error on a held out validation set.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about the test/validation thing. Actually my answer started out as a comment, but I ended up putting it in as an answer instead. I did not want the comment to become to lengthy, thus is skipped the validation/test-thing.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is to do a random search on your hyper parameter space. Trying out random variables is best for a number of reasons, where the most significant is that it is trivial to implement as an outer loop. This approach even beats the famous grid search for a number of reasons. See Bergstra's [Random Search for Hyper parameter optimization](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf).

Here is a quick rundown: split your data into training, validation and test. Write a program with an outer loop which randomly samples a set of hyper parameters (from manually tuned ranges) and train a net on it. Pick the best sample wrt validation set and use that one. Report test error.

You can run 100s of experiments while drinking coffee that way, are somewhat guaranteed to find good solutions (quicker than grid search, but slower than manual search by someone experienced of course) and can even parallelize it trivially by running multiple instances of your program.

Comment: wow, this Bergsta's random search sounds so complicated! But I guess I asked for more rigor : ) I'll research what a validation set is (at the moment not sure how it is different to the test set) and will try to implement what you have suggested. It sounds like a solution to my problem!!! By the way any thought on how the order of the training examples effects the learning by the NN?